# Animate a plot over an image in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to animate a plot of geographic coordinates over an image, in this case a snippet of a map. I've managed to produce a static plot but cannot get it to animate. I've tried to animate using the matplotlib animation function, but haven't had any success with it. I am using pandas to read the csv in to Python and matplotlib.pyplot to plot. Below is the code for the static plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv', header=0)
# find max/min, plug into a website, snip area as png and insert as plotmap
BBox = ((df.LONGITUDE.min(),   df.LONGITUDE.max(),
         df.LATITUDE.min(), df.LATITUDE.max()))
#read the image in, plot points over image
plotmap = "myimage.png"
truthplot = plt.imread(plotmap)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,8),linewidth = 0.1)
ax.scatter(df.LONGITUDE, df.LATITUDE, zorder=1, alpha= 0.5, c='b', s=10)
plottitle = "test"
ax.set_title(plottitle)
ax.set_xlabel("Longitude")
ax.set_ylabel("Latitude")
ax.set_xlim(BBox[0], BBox[1])
ax.set_ylim(BBox[2], BBox[3])

ax.imshow(truthplot, zorder=0, extent = BBox, aspect= 'equal')
plt.show()
```

Some example coordinates:

```
LATITUDE   LONGITUDE
30.112342  10.678982
29.443459  11.678997
29.334221  11.889544
28.993448  12.003847
```

I'm still a newbie; any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


df = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv', header=0)
# find max/min, plug into a website, snip area as png and insert as plotmap
BBox = ((df.LONGITUDE.min(),   df.LONGITUDE.max(),
         df.LATITUDE.min(), df.LATITUDE.max()))
#read the image in, plot points over image
plotmap = "myimage.png"
truthplot = plt.imread(plotmap)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,8),linewidth = 0.1)
plottitle = "test"
ax.set_title(plottitle)
ax.set_xlabel("Longitude")
ax.set_ylabel("Latitude")
ax.set_xlim(BBox[0], BBox[1])
ax.set_ylim(BBox[2], BBox[3])

scat = ax.scatter(df.LONGITUDE, df.LATITUDE, zorder=1, alpha= 0.5, c='b', s=10)
color_data = np.random.random((500, len(df.LATITUDE)))

def update(frame):
    scat.set_array(color_data[frame])
    return scat,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=range(500), blit=True)

ax.imshow(truthplot, zorder=0, extent = BBox, aspect= 'equal')
plt.show()
```

I am not sure what you wanted to be animated, that's why I just made the points blink.
But you can easily change your scatter plot all you want in the update function.
`scat` is a PathCollection, its functions you can find here:
https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection

## UPDATE

If you want to build the path step by step, manipulation the PathCollention is not very convenient. I would recommend recreating the obj.

```
scat = ax.scatter(df.LONGITUDE[0], df.LATITUDE[0], zorder=1, alpha= 0.5, c='b', s=10)

max_frames = 10

def update(frame):
    scat = ax.scatter(df.LONGITUDE[:(frame * (len(df.LONGITUDE) + 1))//max_frames],
                      df.LATITUDE[:(frame * (len(df.LATITUDE) + 1))//max_frames],
                       zorder=1, alpha= 0.5, c='b', s=10)
    return scat,
```

Comment: That's pretty close. Essentially I want the animation to start at the first row of coordinates and plot out the track, row by row. I will take a look at the link you provided. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, if you want to use a scatter plot on a DataFrame directly:

```
BBox = ((df['LONGITUDE'].min(), df['LONGITUDE'].max(),
         df['LATITUDE'].min(), df['LATITUDE'].max()))
plotmap = 'myimage.png'
truthplot = plt.imread(plotmap)
ax = df.plot.scatter(x='LONGITUDE', y='LATITUDE', c='Red')
plottitle = "test"
ax.set_title(plottitle)
ax.set_xlabel("Longitude")
ax.set_ylabel("Latitude")
ax.set_xlim(BBox[0], BBox[1])
ax.set_ylim(BBox[2], BBox[3])

ax.imshow(truthplot, zorder=0, extent = BBox, aspect= 'equal')
plt.show()
```